# Php problem eval/html/php

Tags: php, html, eval, encryption

I've been writing a php/html page encoder/decoder... I know it already exists but it's a university project so go on XDDD

I encode the pages that I want to protect let's say hypothetically with `base64_encode` and when I receive a request of any pages I have a loader that reads the coded page, decrypts it and with `eval` executes it. The real problems arise when I try to decrypt and execute a mixed php/html page. Obviously `eval` can't execute html code so my question is do I really become crazy about splitting the page executing the php code and print the html? And also if I include an encoded php or php/html page do I really have to reuse the method up here?

I hope someone can really help me because i have a week left before the deadline and I can't change the project at this point.

chris here the function and the fisrt calling  in $param[0] i've got the filename called

```
function MyInclude($filename)
{
// create the temp file
$temp_filename = "tmp.php";
$handle = fopen($temp_filename , 'w+');
if (!$handle)
  die('Error creating temp file');

// write the decrypted data, close the handle
$tmp=file_get_contents($filename);

$data=MCrypt_Decode($tmp,'PFL_EPU_V100_mia');

fwrite($handle,$data );
fclose($handle);

// start output buffering to contain any output the script creates
ob_start();

try {
 include($temp_filename);
} catch (Exception $e) {
 die('There was an error in the encrypted file, cannot process');
}

// get the output, clear the buffer
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

//destroy the temp file
unlink($temp_filename);

// now you can output the buffer, if desired:
echo $output;
}

MyInclude($param[0]);
```

the $param[0] file here

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['title']='Home';
 MyInclude("header.php");
?>

<body>
    sono il body <?php echo APP_PATH; ?>
</body>

<?
echo "boss";
 MyInclude("footer.php");
?>
```

any idea about it??? or you need some other code??? let me know T_T

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to decrypt the page, write it to a file, then `include` it? That would let the PHP interpreter do what it does best - interpret PHP documents. That will include HTML/PHP combinations without relying on `eval`.

The outline of that would be:

```
// create the temp file
$temp_filename = "tmp.php";
$handle = fopen($filename , 'w');
if (!$handle)
  die('Error creating temp file');

// write the decrypted data, close the handle
fwrite($handle, $decrypted_data);
fclose($handle);

// start output buffering to contain any output the script creates
ob_start();

try {
 include_once($temp_filename);
} catch (Exception $e) {
 die('There was an error in the encrypted file, cannot process');
}

// get the output, clear the buffer
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

//destroy the temp file
unlink($temp_filename);

// now you can output the buffer, if desired:
echo $output;
```

**Function references**

fopen: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

fwrite: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

fclose: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php

ob_start: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

ob_get_contents: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

ob_end_clean: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php

unlink: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: This is the only way to do it that I can see, because the `eval()` approach is flawed (see my comment on Sam Dufel's answer).

Comment: ok guys! using this solution i'm almost done... i packed in a function the code above obviously with the decode function ;) now i get a really strange error, never seen before  Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error. but if i just put an echo before with a whitespace XD the page load..... (well i get an error for session_start ^^''' so someone knows what the hell is 330 ???

Comment: sorry i wanted to give a return but i posted an incomplete message XDDD

Comment: Look like you have output compression turned on or some other such thing. Without looking at the scripts and output involved, I couldn't begin to guess - that is a browser error, but it could be caused by invalid output from a script.  Try your encrypt/decrypt code on a very simple script first to make sure the concept works, then work your way backward to find the cause of this error. I *suspect* it is caused in your encrypted/decrypted file... using non-UTF8 characters by chance?

Comment: Are you using Chrome browser for this? If so, try in Firefox and let me know what happens. Also, post the code for `MCrypt_Decode` function.

Comment: ok.... actually if i remove all the ob function it will work... now i'm looking for the cause of it!!!!! thanks for all men!!! you saved my scholastic life XD

Comment: Interesting about `ob_start`... that really points to output before the buffer started, maybe a PHP error or something. Try moving `ob_start` to the very very top of the script. Also, double-triple check to see if gzip compression is on, if so, try turning it off and see if that corrects the problem. If removing gzip does stop the problem, then turning off gzip is not the ***solution***, but it does narrow it down. Also, be sure to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can eval() a string that contains mixed html and php, just so long as the  tags are included.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Just been playing with this and it does work, as long as the first bit of code in the string to `eval()` is either an opening tag or valid PHP code. It does NOT work if the start of the file is anything that should be output - e.g. `eval("<div><?php print('hello'); ?></div>");` causes a parse error. This makes the eval approach useless.

Comment: Prepend an opening and closing php tag to the beginning of the string?

Comment: Doesn't work either - it turns out eval not only doesn't require opening `<?php` tags, it doesn't like them either. I failed to CTRL-F5 before.

Answer (score 3):

When `eval()` encounters a php close tag (`?>`), it will stop trying to treat it as php code and just echo everything out until it comes to a php open tag.

The typical solution to your problem is something like this:

```
$file = ... //Your decoded php/html code here

$file = '?>' . $file; //Add a close tag to the beginning;

ob_start();
eval($file);
$output = ob_get_clean();

echo $output; //Or do something else with it... really, if you're 
              //just going to be echoing it you can skip the output buffering
```

Comment: this will do half of the works!!!! now i have only to handle the include/include_once and require/require_once parts and i'm done!! i can't believe that a simple  ?> will change all XDDDDD f*** i tryed to put the code as is ..... T_T

Comment: The include/require stuff is why `eval` is a bad choice, IMO. I suggest that you try my suggestion (writing it as a temp file) before you dig too deeply into parsing out include/require.

Comment: @Chris - this is almost verbatum the method codeigniter uses to load views.  I'm fairly certain that eval will handle embedded includes / requires properly.  The only downside is that it's hard to check for parse errors in the input.

Answer (score 1):

You will need dump the decoded file to another file and `include();` it. The eval approach will not work because it will exit with a parse error if the first item in the file is not either an opening `<?php` tag, or a valid bit of PHP code.

More than this, you will need to find/replace any occurences of `include()`, `require()`, `include_once()`, and `require_once()` within the encrypted file with a different function, to ensure you don't try to execute another encrypted file before it has been decrypted. You could do this at execution (ie decryption) time, but it would be much better to it a encryption time, to minimise the time required to pre-fetch the code before it is executed.

You can define these customised functions to decrypt a file and include/require it in your loader script.

Comment: I'm glad that you agree with my answer, but I don't see the utility in reposting it as your own... ;P

Comment: The only reason I created this as an answer not a comment is because I felt it was crucial to outline the fact `eval()` is not a fail-safe solution, and that you would also need to handle any calls to `include` etc within the file(s) you have encrypted. I would have posted it as comments against yours apart from the fact that a lot of OP's don't bother to read comments... No offence/thunder-stealing meant, and I will freely admit that it was your answer that put me on the right track. If you want to add that info to your answer I will happily delete this one.

Comment: Naaah, just wondering whether you were really ***that*** hungry :P

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description is a bit vague however your problem seems to be solvable with [**output buffering**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Comment: mmmh i've never used the ob i'll read the explanation on the php manual and let's see if i can get out of this hell XDDD

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried decrypting the page, then parsing the text to split out anything between  and then only executing that code?

Comment: yeah but it's really insane and when you have to include a external crypted page you must reparse all the new file with a recorsive system and i don't really like it ... and it's really slow if you have many includes

Comment: very resource hungry approach and also, you still need to output the parts between the code...

Comment: Not sure why it would have to be resource intensive or why it would have to be recursive. Are you checking for all of the includes and replacing them with your encrypted transfer method? Use a loop and a string index starting at 0. Check for an instance of <?php, everything between index and <?php is html, move the index to the location of <?php, eval everything between index and the next ?>, loop until the file is finished.

Comment: It's a lot more system operations than dumping the decrypted code to a file and `include()`ing it though...

Comment: How much time does a single eval statement take? Reading and writing files isn't free either, both methods will require some processing time. Without running the code and doing some comparative analysis / profiling, saying it is "very resource hungry" or that "it's a lot more system operations" seems a bit presumptive.

Comment: It's not the eval's I'm worried about, it's the `strpos()`/`substr()`s that are implied by hunting through the file for occurences of `<?php`, also I have just been playing with this and it turns out, bizarrely, that `eval()` throws a parse error if the string starts with an opening tag. You could either `substr` the opening tags off or prepend a closing tag (bizarre work around I just found) but for more than a very simple file it all mounts up to a lot more byte-code instructions that dumping to a file and including it.